# Orbeon formatting.xpl to show xmlns declarations?

Tags: orbeon, xforms

Code

```
<xforms:output mediatype="text/html" value="xxforms:serialize(xxforms:call-xpl('oxf:/ops/utils/formatting/format.xpl', 'data', instance('message-instance'), 'data')/*, 'xml')"/>
```

Input

```
<REPC_IN000023NL xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">
    ....
    <hl7:patientID xmlns:hl7="urn:hl7-org:v3">
        <hl7:value root="2.16.840.1.113883.2.4.6.3" extension="999999035"/>
    </hl7:patientID>
    ....
</REPC_IN000023NL>
```

Expected a rendering that includes the namespace declaration, but instead the rendering omits exactly that.

Bug or feature?

Comment: Possibly a bug. But I see this code hasn't changed in 5 years, so it's probably not new.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the namespace declaration for the `hl7` prefix, which isn't on the root element, is not produced:

[image: XML output]

I'd recommend you don't use that `format.xpl`; it isn't maintained, has performance issues with large documents, and, as you noticed, doesn't handle some corner cases well (i.e. it's buggy!).

Instead, you can use the `fr:code-mirror` component, which delegates formatting to CodeMirror. It won't do the indenting for you, but [Saxon can do it for you](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation9.1/extensions/functions/serialize.html). [This example](https://gist.github.com/avernet/137ccd0ca06a556e6649) will give you the following output:

[image: Using CodeMirror]

Comment: To date we have always used xxforms:serialize(.,'html') / xxforms:serialize(.,'xml') instead of the proposed saxon:serialize. Does that remain supported?

Comment: We've been toying with the code-mirror route, but it has proven to have very big downsides:
- Only initializes contents at page load and does not refresh contents when you update the instance it reads from [a show stopper]

- Doesn't adhere to the same color scheme as format.xpl and cannot change that

- Doesn't write XML as-is but instead expands closing /> into ></tag>

The last two we can overcome, but the first makes code-mirror useless to us. Any way to force code mirror reinitialization after instance content changes?

Comment: @AlexanderHenket About the `fr:code-mirror` not updating after it is loaded, the "Reset" button in this example (https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/resources-packaged/xbl/orbeon/code-mirror/code-mirror-unittest.xhtml) tests this, and it is working for me. Is this what you are talking about?

Comment: Sort of. I have an arbitrary deep structure in an instance I loop through. I need color coded views at various points. I update the full instance based on an xforms:select1. The contents of the instance now has serialized content at the right locations through the xquery I call. Hence all I do in the form is use (nested) xforms:repeat and do <fr:code-mirror ref="."/> at the right locations. Code mirror does not reinitialize while the rest of the contents are updated normally. format.xpl does not have that limitation and just responds to instance updates.

Comment: @AlexanderHenket OK, then I imagine that you can either fix the issue in `format.xpl` and contribute that change to the project through a pull request on GitHub, or if you think there is a bug with `<fr:code-mirror>` submit a reproducible case (the mailing list http://discuss.orbeon.com/  is most likely a better place to do this), and we'll open an issue.